# How do i check if two constraints are the same using swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to write a test to check if the location of a stack view is where I expect it to be.  In code I've set the stack view bottomAnchor = to the superview.bottomAnchor (using the appropriate method).  I've written the following assertion in my test case:

```
func test_MainMenu_At_BottomLeft () {
    let vcv = ViewController().view
    let sv = ViewController().view.subviews[0]

    XCTAssert(vcv.bottomAnchor == sv.bottomAnchor)
}
```

It always fails. I've tried casting to CGFloat, creating other temporary anchors but all of it pointless.  There doesn't seem to be any properties of bottomAnchor that I could use.  The stack view is laid out correctly and the build passes with no issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot compare two different objects. What you want to do is to compare the values contained in the attributes of the class. Look at the value of the constant , multiplier etc of the NSLayoutContraint

Comment: The location of a view is its _frame_.